# How to whitelist inline event handler using nonce

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, content-security-policy, nonce

I have been used nonce in order to allow inline script against content security policy and it's working fine, but it also blocking inline event handler.

I used nonce but not getting how to whitelist inline event handler

Home

It should not block inline event handler also.

Comment: Have you considered trying to attach the handler properly using Javascript instead? Inilne handlers are pretty much universally considered to be a pretty bad idea

Comment: It's an legacy will cause millions of changes and issues too reason why looking for idea where i can allow inline event handler like i did using nonce for inline scripts whitelisting.

Comment: All you can do is allow `unsafe-inline`, which effectively turns off CSP for scripts.

Comment: it not completely secure, cause xss, i used nonce, it works to allow inline script but, still i don't use unsafe inline, csp block inline event handler.